# Shifting all rows in dask dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dask

In Pandas, there is a method DataFrame.shift(n) which shifts the contents of an array by n rows, relative to the index, similarly to np.roll(a, n). I can't seem to find a way to get a similar behaviour working with Dask. I realise things like row-shifts may be difficult to manage with Dask's chunked system, but I don't know of a better way to compare each row with the subsequent one.

What I'd like to be able to do is this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.DataFrame as dd

with pd.HDFStore(path) as store:
    data = dd.from_hdf(store, 'sim')[col1]
    shifted = data.shift(1)

    idx = data.apply(np.sign) != shifted.apply(np.sign)
```

in order to create a boolean series indicating the locations of sign changes in the data. (I am aware that method would also catch changes from a signed value to zero)
I would then use the boolean series to index a different Dask dataframe for plotting.

Comment: `shifted = data.sign() != data.sign().shift()` should work rather than use `apply`

Comment: From a check of the source, I'm pretty sure that method is only implemented for Dask arrays, not dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Rolling functions

Currently [dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) does not implement the `shift` operation.  It could though if you [raise an issue](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/new).  In principle this is not so dissimilar from rolling operations that dask.dataframe *does* support, like `rolling_mean`, `rolling_sum`, etc..

Actually, if you were to create a Pandas function that adheres to the same API as these `pandas.rolling_foo` functions then you can use the `dask.dataframe.rolling.wrap_rolling` function to turn your pandas style rolling function into a `dask.dataframe` rolling function.

```py
dask.dataframe.rolling_sum = wrap_rolling(pandas.rolling_sum)
```

Comment: Is this possible with a GroupBy object? Attempting something much the same as Troy above, grouped by index. My current `apply, shift` attempt is painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help to shift down the series.

```py
s = dd_df['column'].rolling(window=2).sum() - dd_df['column']
```

**Edit (03/09/2019):**

When you are rolling and finding the sum, for a particular row,

```
result[i] = row[i-1] + row[i]
```

Then by subtracting the old value of the column from the result, you are doing the following operation:

```
final_row[i] = result[i] - row[i]
```

Which equals:

```
final_row[i] = row[i-1] + row[i] - row[i]
```

Which ultimately results in the whole column getting shifted down once.

**Tip:**

If you want to shift it down multiple rows, you should actually execute the whole operation again that many times with the same window.

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer?