# Compute forward difference with Dask DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, dask

How do I compute the first discrete difference using Dask DataFrame?  Or, in "Pandas speak", how do I do [`pandas.DataFrame.diff()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) in Dask?  Mathematically, the operation is very simple: subtract a column vector from a copy of itself shifted by one or more rows.

I have tried implementing `diff()` in Dask in the following ways, none of which works (yet):

- `df - df.shift(periods=1)` works in Pandas.  But Dask DataFrame doesn't have a `shift()` method.
- `df.values[:-1] - df.values[1:]` works in Pandas.  But I can't see how to index into a Dask DataFrame by *position*.

My current best idea for implementing `diff` would be to wrap some custom code in `dask.dataframe.rolling.wrap_rolling`, as suggested in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225275/shifting-all-rows-in-dask-dataframe/34226468#34226468) (although I haven't been able to find any documentation on *how to do this*).  Or wrap some custom code using Dask Delayed?  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Yup, I would recommend using wrap_rolling.  If you [raise an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new) to make this into user-accessible API I suspect that someone would take it on.  (or maybe this is something that you would like to contribute to help others?)

Comment: @MRocklin thanks for the suggestion!  I have just created [a feature request on Dask's issue queue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `diff` method has now been added to both DataFrame and Series, in this PR: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1769. Works the same as it does in pandas.